# How to get only the outer paragraph text without the text inside anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, html

The following code:

```
$(".done").click(function(){
    var x = $(this).parent().text();
    $("#display").html(x);
});
```

on running displays `This is a paragraph Done`

my html file is as:

```
<p> This is a paragraph <a href="#" class = "done">Done</a></p>
<p id="display"></p>
```

I want to display as: `This is a paragraph`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the `textNode` inside `p`. Use **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** to get all inner elements and use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to filter `textNode` from them.

```js
$(".done").click(function() {
  var x = $(this).parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).text();
  $("#display").html(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph <a href="#" class="done">Done</a></p>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! But what does the return statement mean?

Comment: @user3762146 `For each element, if the function returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded.`
( taken from https://api.jquery.com/filter/ )